# determine conditions if any on b's to make the system consistent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Determine conditions on th b's if any in order to guarantee that the linear system is consistent. 
$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cccc|c}
      1&-1&3&2&b1\\
      -2&1&5&1&b2\\-3&2&2&-1&b3\\4&-3&1&3&b4
    \end{array}
\right] $$

The book says the answer is b1=b3+b4, b2= 2b3+b4.

However when I do it I come to the answer b3=b2-b1, b4=2b1-b2.

Am I doing this wrong? Is it the same answer? Are both answers acceptable?

If not please show how to get the answer.

Comment: Your solution implies $$b_3+b_4=b_1$$ (just add your equations).

Comment: You also get $$b_2=b_1+b_3=b_3+b_4+b_3=2b_3+b_4$$ Your solution is actually correct.

Comment: Both answers are equivalent. You should be able to verify this yourself at this point though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From book's answer.

b4=b2-2b3

Then put value of b4 in b1=b3+b4.

b1=b3+b2-2b3

b1=b2-b3

b3=b2-b1

Your answer.

Similarly other one.